# How to handle admob Interstitial in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, admob

Hi I want to handle my admob Interstitial and show it every 60 seconds. In Java we do postDelayed(), can you tell me please how to make it with C# ?

This is my code:

```
AdManager.Instance.ShowInterstitial();
```

Comment: yes you can achieve that however that is disallowed interstitial implementation https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6201362?hl=en

Comment: @AmodGokhale yeah thank you but if user is afk (away from keyboard, not active) for sometime I think it's allowed because the ad won't surprise him he will see it when he comes back to continue his activity. Am I wrong? :D

Comment: yes its disallowed policy. You cannot put two consecutive interstitial ad unless there are 2 clicks ( actions ) between them

Answer (score 0):

I used this cod eto acheive that if anyone wants to:

```
Invoke("DoSomething", 60) //DoSomething will happen in 60seconds
```

And:

```
public void DoSomething() {
////your code here
}
```